# I have figured out part of this program but I can't get past creating the subtotal

Tags: python

The program should be:

```
    <Program> Welcome to the checkout counter!  How many items are you purchasing today?
    <User> 3 (user presses Enter key)
    <Program> Please enter the name of product 1:
    <User> chicken (user presses Enter key)
    <Program> And how much does chicken cost?  
    <User> 3.50 (user presses Enter key)
    <Program> Please enter the name of product 2:  
    <User> chips (user presses Enter key)
    <Program> And how much does chips cost?  
    <User> 1.25 (user presses Enter key)
    <Program> Please enter the name of product 3: 
    <User> gum (user presses Enter key)
    <Program> And how much does gum cost?
    <User> .99 (user presses Enter key)
    <Program>
    Your order was:
    chicken $3.50
    chips $1.25
    gum $.99
    Your subtotal comes to $5.74.  With 9% sales tax, your total is $6.19.
    Please enter cash amount:
    <User> 20.00 (user presses Enter key)
    <Program>
    I owe you back $13.81. 
    Thank you for shopping with us!
```

Hint: You will need two separate lists for this assignment.

I have so far:

```
    numitems = int(input("Welcome to the checkout counter! How many items are you purchasing today?"))
    products = []
    prices = []
    for item in range(1, numitems + 1):
        product = raw_input ("Please enter the name of product %u:" %item)
        products.insert(item,product)
        price = (raw_input("And how much does %s cost?" %product))
        Price = str(float(price))
        prices.insert(item,Price)
    print "Your order was"
    for i in range (len(products)):
        print products[i], "$" + prices[i]
```

I cannot get past the subtotal input because it won't let me sum the list prices.

Comment: You're storing your prices as strings - that's why you can't sum them. Remove the `str()` when assigning `Price`, and you should be able to sum them. You will also need to update your call to `print` to this: `print products[i], "$" + str(prices[i])`...

Comment: Thank you!! That obviously helped tremendously!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
def input_num(s, f=float):
    while True:
        try:
            return f(raw_input(s))
        except ValueError:
            print "Input must be a {}.".format(f.__name__)

items = {}
for n in xrange(input_num("Welcome to the checkout counter! How many items are you purchasing today? ", int)):
    product = raw_input("Please enter the name of product {}: ".format(n+1))
    items[product] = input_num("And how much does {} cost? ".format(product))
subtotal = sum(items.values())
total = subtotal*1.09

print "Your order was: "
print "\n".join("{} ${}".format(i[0], i[1]) for i in items.items())
print "Your subtotal comes to ${}.  With 9% sales tax, your total is ${}.".format(subtotal, total)
print "I owe you back {}.\nThank you for shopping with us!".format(input_num("Please enter cash amount: ") - total)
```

Hope this helps! If you have any questions about how/why I did something, please ask.